# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:22 mismatched input ',' expecting < near 'array' in list type

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am attempting to create the following by using Hadoop Hive Query:

```
create table tweets (
created_at string,
entities struct <
hashtags: array ,
text: string>>,
media: array ,
media_url: string,
media_url_https: string,
sizes: array >,
url: string>>,
urls: array ,
url: string>>,
user_mentions: array ,
name: string,
screen_name: string>>>,
geo struct <
coordinates: array ,
type: string>,
id bigint,
id_str string,
in_reply_to_screen_name string,
in_reply_to_status_id bigint,
in_reply_to_status_id_str string,
in_reply_to_user_id int,
in_reply_to_user_id_str string,
retweeted_status struct <
created_at: string,
entities: struct <
hashtags: array ,
text: string>>,
media: array ,
media_url: string,
media_url_https: string,
sizes: array >,
url: string>>,
urls: array ,
url: string>>,
user_mentions: array ,
name: string,
screen_name: string>>>,
geo: struct <
coordinates: array ,
type: string>,
id: bigint,
id_str: string,
in_reply_to_screen_name: string,
in_reply_to_status_id: bigint,
in_reply_to_status_id_str: string,
in_reply_to_user_id: int,
in_reply_to_user_id_str: string,
source: string,
text: string,
user: struct <
id: int,
id_str: string,
name: string,
profile_image_url_https: string,
protected: boolean,
screen_name: string,
verified: boolean>>,
source string,
text string,
user struct <
id: int,
id_str: binary,
name: string,
profile_image_url_https: string,
protected: boolean,
screen_name: string,
verified: boolean>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

The error that I am receiving is:

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:22 mismatched input ',' expecting < near 'array' in list type

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have extra '>' symbol on line five

Answer (score -1):

from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)

when you use

```
array_type
  : ARRAY < data_type >

where data_type
  : primitive_type
  | array_type
  | map_type
  | struct_type
  | union_type
```